# Multiple Notifications from Foreground service Android

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm working on an application where I need to show notifications 5 times a day ...from a foreground service..the purpose of using the foreground services is to be able to display notification even if the 
application is closed . so I want to start the service as applications starts and schedule its notification timing accordingly I have tried using the snippet provided on android developers forum but its not working for me  ... any help and sample code is highly appreciated Thanks

Comment: While you need a notification to use a foreground service, the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 2):

If the notifications are to be fired at a fixed time, you may not need a foreground service. It is a bad idea to keep a service running just to show notifications. Schedule those five times using an `AlarmManager`.

You can find tutorial for it in google.
You would need to schedule alarms one by one. Foe ex..when alarm manager wakes your app the first time , then schedule a second alarm and son on.. You may not be able to set 5 concurrent alarm schedules. Do it one by one..

Comment: thnaks for reply but alaram manager removes the previously qued alaram when u que a new 1 ...and i 5 got of them to que
and it also shows it in alarams ...

Comment: one more thing how can i schedule another alaram when application is closed ? service is necessary for that ..

Comment: when your first alarm will wake up your app, then schedule the 2nd alarm..A service is not needed